# How can I extract everything in between "_" characters starting with nth occurrence of said character (from the end of the string)?

Tags: regex, re2

How can I extract below parameters with Regex using the [RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) (not all features are available)?

What I would need is to extract (different Regex for each):

1. Parameter that appears after third occurrence of `_` from the end of the string and until second occurrence of `_` (from the end of the string)
2. Parameter that appears after second occurrence of `_` from the end of the string and until first occurrence of `_` (from the end of the string)
3. Parameter that appears after first occurrence of `_` from the end of
   the string and until first occurrence of `.` in the string (from the end of the string)
4. Everything up until first occurrence of `.` from the end of the string

Lets say that we have below string:

- Parameter1_Parameter3_Parameter4_ParamaterA_ParameterB_ParamaterC.mp4

In this case I want to extract:

1. ParameterA
2. ParameterB
3. ParameterC
4. mp4

Couple of notes:

- There can be a lot of additional strings in between "_" at the start
  of the string
- Parameter A, ParameterB, ParameterC and "." position are always in
  same spot (if looking from the end of the string)
- mp4 can be of any length, it's not fixed to 3 characters

---

Best thing I did so far is to extract **_ParameterA_ParameterB_ParameterC.mp4** with `((?:_[^_]*){3})$` but that's not what I need.

Also figured out how to pull ".mp4" ( `(\..*)$` )but can't figure out how to get it without `.`.

---

I figured out how to pull "mp4" with RE2. It's `([^.]*)$`.

Comment: Why is 1. Parameter A? Shouldn't it be C?

Comment: Indeed! I just messed them up in first and second list. But basically it's ParamterA, ParameterB, ParameterC and mp4 what I'd need to extract but Re2 regex is giving me headache. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are four suitable regular expressions utilizing positive lookarounds. Let me know if they work:

```
"(?<=\_)[^_]+(?=_[^_]+_[^_]+\.)"
"(?<=\_)[^_]+(?=_[^_]+\.)"
"(?<=\_)[^_]+(?=\.)"
"(?<=\.).*$"
```

As Google Data Studio cannot implement lookaround, here is an alternative workaround with multiple steps, which is written in R but can be translated to your language of choice:

```r
text1 <- "Parameter1_Parameter3_Parameter4_ParamaterA_ParameterB_ParamaterC.mp4"

last_three <- str_extract(text1, "[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+\\..+")

str_extract(last_three, "^[^_]+")

str_replace_all(str_extract(last_three, "_[^_\\.]+_"), "_", "")

str_replace(str_extract(last_three, "[^_\\.]+\\."), "\\.", "")

str_replace(str_extract(last_three, "\\..+$"), "\\.", "")
```

https://support.google.com/datastudio/table/6379764?hl=en

Google Data Studio has the required commands for this: REGEXP_EXTRACT and REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: These ones are great but sadly it seems like positive lookarounds do not work with Re2 ( https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax ). :( I'll make sure to bookmark this, it might come handy for some other project though.

Comment: One regex step is unlikely to benefit you in this case. You are probably better off splitting the string by underscore or period, and selecting the last, second to last, third to last, and fourth to last vector elements. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Or you can use multiple functions as in my most recent edits. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single capture group to match the first parameter and always capture the extension at the end of the string.

For the second to n parameters use optional capture groups.

If you don't want to cross newlines, you could change the character class to `[^_\r\n]*`

```
_([^_]*)(?:_([^_]*)(?:_([^_]*))?)?\.(\w+)$
```

- `_([^_]*)` Match `_` and capture 0+ times any char except `_` in **group 1**
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `_([^_]*)` Match `_` and capture 0+ times any char except `_` in **group 2**
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `_([^_]*)` Match `_` and capture 0+ times any char except `_` in **group 3**
  - `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `)?` Close the whole non capture group and make it optional
- `\.(\w+)` Match a dot and 1+ word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DViLnK/1)